# Converting GPUImage MultipleBlend From OBJ-C To Swift

Tags: swift, gpuimage

I am in the process of converting my GPUImage app to Swift but I am having some trouble converting the following.

```
GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Elevate.png" ofType:nil]]];

        [lookupImageSource forceProcessingAtSize:sourceImage.size];

        GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter * blendFilter = [[GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter alloc] init];

        GPUImageOpacityFilter *opacityFilter = [[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init];
        opacityFilter.opacity = sliderValue;

        [lookupImageSource addTarget:opacityFilter];

        [stillImageSource addTarget:blendFilter];
        [opacityFilter addTarget:blendFilter];

        [blendFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

        [stillImageSource processImage];
        [lookupImageSource processImage];

        finishedImage = [blendFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:sourceImage.imageOrientation];
```

At the minute I have converted to the following but I am getting errors when running the code.

```
let filterOpacity = OpacityAdjustment()
            filterOpacity.opacity = 1

            let filterImage = PictureInput.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "Elevate.png")!)
            filterImage.addTarget(filterOpacity)


            let filterMultiplyBlend = MultiplyBlend()
            filterMultiplyBlend.addTarget(filterOpacity)


            imageOutput = sourceImage!.filterWithPipeline{input, output in
                input --> filterMultiplyBlend --> output
            }
```

I am getting this error as output.

> Warning: tried to add target beyond target's input capacity -->
>   Pipeline.swift: addTarget(_:atTargetIndex:): 43

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        let filterOpacity = OpacityAdjustment()
        filterOpacity.opacity = 1

        let filterImage = PictureInput.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "Elevate.png")!)

        let filterMultiplyBlend = MultiplyBlend()

        imageOutput = sourceImage!.filterWithPipeline{input, output in
            input --> filterOpacity --> filterMultiplyBlend --> output
        }
```

Comment: tried but it hasn't worked, the opacity filter needs to be applied to the image input.